# Find SSN with same digit including dash using oracle REGEXP_LIKE function

Tags: regex, oracle

I am trying to filter out SSNs having same digits with dash (-).Meaning all digits in SSN are same and follow xxx-xx-xxxx format.

Examples:

**Correct filtered values** : 111-11-1111, 000-00-0000.

**Wrong   filtered values** : 123-45-6789, 012-34-5678

Data is in Oracle database so I am using REGEXP_LIKE function and my sql is below.

```
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE id_typ='SSN' 
AND REGEXP_LIKE(id,'^([0-9])(?=\1{2}-\1{2}-\1{4})[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$');
```

You can test regular expression at https://regex101.com/r/rA2xA2/13

Above query does not return me any data !

If I replace above regular expression with **^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$** than it returns me data but having different digits ssn which is correct behavior but wrong requirement.

So what am I missing ?

Comment: it might be simpler to have a `not in` condition with these ten scenarios you do not want to see in lieu of a regular expression.

Comment: [`^(\d)\1{2}-\1{2}-\1{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/rA2xA2/14) is much shorter

Comment: So, is it given (or are you testing already) that the strings are in the correct format, 'xxx-xx-xxxx', where the x stand for digits? Or do you need to check that as well?

Comment: @mathguy It is given. column already has data in 'xxx-xx-xxxx' format. I just specified it so it will be covered.

Comment: @Patrick this is part of giant query I am writing so wanted to have it filter by reg exp instead having ten IN or NOT IN . ctwheels got it though.

Comment: @ctwheels correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: I offered a "funny" solution, but the correct answer is actually what @ctwheels posted in a Comment above this one. EDIT: I saw you noticed the same thing. I agree!

Comment: @Ankit You're welcome, I've posted it as an answer below.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, I still like your solution though haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/rA2xA2/14)

```
^(\d)\1{2}-\1{2}-\1{4}$
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(\d)` Capture any digit into capture group 1
- `\1{2}` Matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capture group exactly twice
- `-` Match the hyphen character `-` literally
- `\1{2}` Matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capture group exactly twice
- `-` Match the hyphen character `-` literally
- `\1{4}` Matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capture group exactly four times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 2):

Here is a funny (but correct!) way to check for "all digits are equal" in a social security number. Assumption: It is given that the input strings have length exactly 11, the fourth and the seventh characters are dashes (`-`) and the rest are digits.

```
with
  inputs ( ssn ) as (
    select '123-00-4020' from dual union all
    select '333-33-3333' from dual union all
    select '013-35-4444' from dual
  )
-- End of simulated inputs. Query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select ssn
from   inputs
where  mod(to_number(ssn, '999G99G9999', 'nls_numeric_characters='',-'''), 111111111) = 0
;

SSN
-----------
333-33-3333
```

Explanation: I interpret the `ssn` as a number, written with "thousands" separator, which I declare to be the dash, not the comma (as in English speaking countries) or the dot (as in most of the rest of the world). I do so in the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS parameter: I declare `,` to be the decimal separator and `-` to be the "group" separator. Oracle allows the "group" separator to appear anywhere - it is called "group" and not "thousands" separator precisely for that reason. In some cultures, groups are not necessarily thousands; for example a common Indian notation for 100 million is `10,00,00,000` - and Oracle accommodates that. By doing so, it also accommodates my hack - using a "group separator" when it is convenient, even though that wasn't the intended meaning.

The rest is trivial; a nine digit number has all equal digits if and only if it is divisible by 111111111.

If you want to **ex**clude these strings, change `=` to `!=`.